# Get match range value from the array in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have below types of array in my vue js. Now I want to find the value key value of match the range.
So it's fall in 25 range so my output should be 25. I tried below code but it always return all the range.

```
let input = 5
let myarray = [25, 100, 250 ,500]
this.myarray.forEach((val, q) => {
  if(val >= input) {
    //console.log('Do something here')
  } 
});
```

---

**Edit:**

My input is `5` and it's fall between `0-25` so I want to get `25` value from my array. Same if my input is `30` it's fall between `25-100`, in this case I want `100` as value from the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the index of the first value that is greater then input. I am assuming the array is sorted,

```js
let input = 5
let myarray = [25, 100, 250 ,500]
let index = myarray.findIndex(val => {
  return val >= input;
});
if(index <= -1) {
    index = myarray.length -1;
}

console.log(myarray[index]);
```

Comment: Hi in the above solution when there is 0 at the beginning it returns 1 index and when 0 is not at the beginning of the array it returns it returns 0 index. I want index 0 when the 0 present at the beginning of the array

Comment: Because it is greater than 0 but less than 25. That is why it returns 25. On the other hand, when 25 is the first index, no item is greater than 5 that is why we are returning the first index.